# Detecting Javascript as Part of Validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Like everyone else who develops forms, I worry about validation and preventing users from entering malicious data.  Javascript validation is so much more immediate and neat, but of course there is the issue that someone can just turn off Javascript.

What I've wondering, is it a legitimate option to disable forms for users who have Javascript disabled?  Does it work, or can malicious visitors get around it anyway? Is it a bad idea for other reasons?

I've seen older discussions on this general topic:

[How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

[How do I know if Javascript has been turned off inside browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097/how-do-i-know-if-javascript-has-been-turned-off-inside-browser)

What are the current methods and thinking on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable forms?" No matter what, you **must** perform input validation on the server.

Answer (score 1):

> What I've wondering, is it a legitimate option to disable forms for users who have Javascript disabled?

It's anti-social at best. Be [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

> Does it work, or can malicious visitors get around it anyway? Is it a bad idea for other reasons?

Attackers can get around *any* defences implemented on the client. Your public interface is HTTP. You need to implement any security checks behind it (i.e. server side).

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the informations that visitors write on your form in PHP. It's more safer.

Comment: Who said anything about PHP?

Comment: There is a high probability he use ajax, so if this is the case, it's more safer to control variable on PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to detect Javascript is to add a class to  of 'no-js'.

Then if you use Modernizr it will replace the 'no-js' class with 'js'

Or if you don't want to use Modernizr you can remove the code yourself through Javascript very easily.